# How to group an array of dynamic objects based on an a property value in react js / javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have an object like this -

```
[{"genericName":"genesName test","genericId":3,"code":"generics"},{"genericName":"genesName fhfghsd","genericId":8,"code":"generics"},{"genericName":"genesName fhld","genericId":11,"code":"generics"}]
```

I want to make it like this -

```
{"generics": {"genericId": 3}},
{"generics": {"genericId": 8}},
{"generics": {"genericId": 11}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to group them like this? 
`{  "generics": [3, 8, 11]  }`
Question seems a little vague.

Comment: @srx , it will same as follow :(

Comment: here generics part is static, i can change the object with -
[{"genericName":"genesName test","genericId":3"},
{"genericName":"genesName fhfghsd","genericId":8},
{"genericName":"genesName fhld","genericId":11}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `map` method of `Array`:

```js
const obj = [{
  "genericName": "genesName test",
  "genericId": 3,
  "code": "generics"
}, {
  "genericName": "genesName fhfghsd",
  "genericId": 8,
  "code": "generics"
}, {
  "genericName": "genesName fhld",
  "genericId": 11,
  "code": "generics"
}]

const mapObjToResult = (item, idx, arr) => {
  return {
    [item.code]: {
      genericId: item.genericId
    }
  }
}

const result = obj.map(mapObjToResult);

console.log(result);
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and destructuring

```js
const data = [
  { genericName: "genesName test", genericId: 3, code: "generics" },
  { genericName: "genesName fhfghsd", genericId: 8, code: "generics" },
  { genericName: "genesName fhld", genericId: 11, code: "generics" },
];

const res = data.map(({ code, genericId }) => ({ [code]: { genericId } }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have arrays of Objects, then this one?

```
let gens = [
  {"genericName":"genesName test","genericId":3,"code":"generics"},
  {"genericName":"genesName fhfghsd","genericId":8,"code":"generics"},
  {"genericName":"genesName fhld","genericId":11,"code":"generics"}
]

result = gens.map(item => ({ [item.code] : {genericId: item.genericId}})
```